# SSL issues when use Supersized Slideshow with OpenCart

Tags: php, jquery, ssl, opencart, supersized

I have Using Supersized Slideshow in OpenCart. but when use SSL so not change HTTPS image path in Supersized Slideshow.

You can see Supersized Slideshow below code.

How to fix? please help me. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({

                    // Functionality
                    slide_interval          :   5000, // Length between transitions
                    transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed        :   750,        // Speed of transition

                    // Components                           
                    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
<?php $i = count($banners); foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
<?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
{image : '<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>', title : '<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>', thumb : '<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>', url : '<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>'} <?php if($i>1){ echo ","; }?>
<?php } else { ?>
{image : '<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>', title : '<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>', thumb : '<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>'}<?php if($i>1){ echo ","; }?>
<?php } ?>
    <?php $i--; } ?>    
            ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `$this->config->get('XYZ');` in HTML templates directly and it is a shame that OpenCart allows developers to do that (and other creepy things) in templates...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Normally support SSL in OpenCart. but Here, i have using spersized slider jquery & it slider html code in jquery. so when I use SSL so not it image path change to HTTPS. You can see above jquery code. can you any more guide for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you set the image in the back end to an absolute path, e.g. `http://www.example.com/image/data/banner1.jpg`

If you can get away with it, set it to `/image/data/banner1.jpg` or even `//www.example.com/image/data/banner1.jpg`